# Two "providedIn: 'root'" services with the same name

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's assume that there are two different services in two different project categories, but both have the same name.
`/app/services/category1/my.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

`/app/services/category2/my.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Is it okay to have two different services with the same name `providedIn: 'root'`?

Comment: Does the application work as expected when you do this? Have you tried it to see how it behaves?

Comment: @P.Richards, application seems to work properly, but I would like to know any potential pitfalls.

Comment: It should be fine, they're different classes and the class itself becomes the injection token, not its name.

Comment: Thank you Ingo. Class as the injection token seems to be enought explenatory here for me. No service class name gonna be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a provider, note that these two equal:

```
providers: [
    ...
    SomeService
]
```

```
providers: [
    ...
    {provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService}
]
```

So as you see, a class is used to declare the provider, and one class is not equal to another class. **It's ok.**